# delete sent sms using Receiver's Number instead of Sender's number

Tags: android

I am using this code (given below) to delete sent sms, and this code requires the sender's number (my device's number) but I want to delete sms using receiver's number (number at which I am sending sms). Please tell how can I do that?

**Code:**

```
public void deleteSMS(Context ctx, String message, String number) {
        try {
            Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms");
            Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long id = c.getLong(0);
                    long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                    String address = c.getString(2);
                    String body = c.getString(5);
                    String date = c.getString(3);
                    Log.e("log>>>", "0>" + c.getString(0) + "1>" + c.getString(1)   + "2>" + c.getString(2) + "<-1>"  + c.getString(3) + "4>" + c.getString(4)+ "5>" + c.getString(5));
//                    Log.e("log>>>", "date" + c.getString(0));

//                    if (body.contains(getResources().getText(R.string.invite_text).toString()) && address.equals(number)) {
                    if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                        // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                        int rows = ctx.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",new String[] { c.getString(4) });
                        Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success......... rows: "+rows);
                        Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success......... body: "+body);
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
            //Log.e("log>>>", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deleteSMS(Context ctx, String message, String number) {
    try {
        Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor1 = ctx.getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                        "body", "type"}, null, null, null);
        ((Activity)ctx).startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] columns = new String[]{"address", "person", "date", "body", "type"};
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
            Log.e("Count", count);
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
                if (type.equals("2")) // 2 for Sent Sms
                {
                    String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                    String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                    String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                    String body = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                    if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                        // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                        int rows = ctx.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?", new String[]{c.getString(4)});
                        Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success......... rows: " + rows);
                        Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success......... body: " + body);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```